# Chart js for doughnut chart not working on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

My Html code is as follows

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="ibox ">
                <div class="ibox-title">
                    <h5>Ticket Overdue Pie Chart </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="ibox-content">
                    <div>
                        <canvas id="dnghclp " height="140"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using chartjs charts on my web page. it is working properly on html page. but when I load them to server in php page it did not show any graph there. I have two graphs one is line and another is bar with following code.

```
var pendchart1 = {
  labels: ["Client","User"],
  datasets: [{
  data: [3,6],
  backgroundColor: 
  ["#e580ff","#ccf2ff","#f0b3ff","#ff704d","#ffff4d"]
}]
} ;
 var doughnpending = {
   responsive: true
 };
  var ctx6 = document.getElementById("dnghclp").getContext("2d");//here error 'getContext' of null
      new Chart(ctx6, {type: 'doughnut', data: pendchart1, options:doughnpending});
```

Answer (score 0):

You added space in canvas id attribute `"dnghclp "` in html. That's why you get an error.

Also you should call `getElementById` method after `DOM` is ready.

You can use `onload` method which fired when the whole page has loaded.

Like:

```
   window.onload = function(){

    var ctx6 = document.getElementById("dnghclp").getContext("2d");
    new Chart(ctx6, {type: 'doughnut', data: pendchart1, options:doughnpending});

   }
```

Comment: its problem of space thanks now work  "dnghclp"  really appreciate your answer